# Padilicious Javascript code is not working, not sure why

Tags: javascript, swipe

I'm using the code from padilicious which allows swipe detection (http://padilicious.com/code/touchevents/). It's not working for me and I can't seem to figure out why. I have looked at other answers on this website for similar questions and followed their solutions and still no luck.

I saved the javascript code from padilicious in a file called swipesense.js in a folder called "js" in my root directory. The following goes in my header:

```
<script src='$root/js/swipesense.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
```

The code below appears in my body:

```
<div class='main_image' 
            ontouchstart='touchStart(event,'main_image');'  
            ontouchend='touchEnd(event, $next_slideURL, $previous_slideURL);' 
            ontouchmove='touchMove(event);' 
            ontouchcancel='touchCancel(event);'>

            <a href='$next_slideURL' style='display:block'>
                    <img src='$root/$item_path/$slideFile' alt='$slideCaption from $projectTitle\n [hidden]' style='max-width:832px; max-height:500px' title='$projectTitle: $slideCaption. \nclick for next slide ($next_slideCaption). '>
            </a>
</div>
```

My processingRoutine() method is as follows:

```
function processingRoutine() {
    var swipedElement = document.getElementById(triggerElementID);
    if ( swipeDirection == 'left' ) {
        window.location.href = "www.nba.com";       
    } else if ( swipeDirection == 'right' ) {
        window.location.href = "www.nba.com";
    }
}
```

Note: In my  tag, I only have class='main_image' without id='main_image'. I'm assuming they are interchangeable. I might be wrong (and let me know if I am), but I've tried including the id option as well and it didn't work either.

I really don't understand why this won't work. Any help would be appreciated!

(Update: I know my swipe is detected since swiping the main_image div does not cause the page to scroll, which it would without the padilicious code. Now I'm just not sure why the routine doesn't work. Any ideas?)

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow.  Is the location of your Swipesense file actually `http://example.com/$root/js/swipesense.js`?  Also, if the file _was_ actually in that location, what errors show up in the developer console (if any) that might relate to the problem at hand?  If you haven't already, you might want to take a look at the [About] page to learn more about how Stack Overflow works.  Thanks!

Comment: @Qantas94Heavy Yes, I'm pretty sure it is. When I open the source code in my browser it gives the right link (I'm also running other scripts from the same directory that work). I just checked the web console and I'm getting "JQuery is not defined" and below a link to the image that's displaying on the screen (i.e. the one I want to be able to swipe). Not sure that related, but it's the only error that shows up

Comment: Is your `processingRoutine()` function part of a larger file that uses jQuery anywhere?

Comment: @Qantas94Heavy I know that it detects a swipe. This is because without the code, swiping <div class = "main_image"> up and down would cause the page to scroll up and down. With the code, swiping the "main_image" doesn't do anything. I've adjusted the code (see original post) to try and test out simpler routines to see if maybe passing the two extra variables was the problem, but still no luck. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured this out and I thought I would post it on here in case anyone else has a similar problem.

In the  tag you must have an id set. You must include this same id as the second parameter in the touchStart function. To correct the code from the question:

```
<div class='main_image' id='swipe'
        ontouchstart='touchStart(event,'swipe');'  
        ontouchend='touchEnd(event, $next_slideURL, $previous_slideURL);' 
        ontouchmove='touchMove(event);' 
        ontouchcancel='touchCancel(event);'>
```

the id name doesn't have to correspond to the class name (quite obvious, but just thought I'd mention it regardless).

Hope this solves someone else's problem as well!